# How to fix "Memory Error" while fetching feeds from hailataxii service?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fetching feeds from **Hailataxii** service using Python's **libtaxii** library. It has 9 feeds, I have successfully fetched 6 feeds but 3 of the feeds are giving me **Memory Error**.

I have run this program on Linux with 15GB RAM, I tracked it for 6 hours and the memory utilization was exceeding and after 12 hours when I checked the progress again, it was displaying **Memory Error**.

```
import libtaxii as t
import libtaxii.messages_11 as tm11
import libtaxii.clients as tc
from libtaxii.common import generate_message_id
from libtaxii.constants import *

RESULTING_FOLDER = 'results'

FEEDS = [
    'Abuse_ch',
    'CyberCrime_Tracker',
    'EmergingThreats_rules',
    'Lehigh_edu',
    'MalwareDomainList_Hostlist',
    'blutmagie_de_torExits',
    'dataForLast_7daysOnly',
    'dshield_BlockList',
    'phishtank_com'
]

USERNAME = 'guest'

PASSWORD = 'guest'


def main(username, password, feeds, result_folder):
    client = tc.HttpClient()
    client.set_auth_type(tc.HttpClient.AUTH_BASIC)
    client.set_auth_credentials({'username': username, 'password': password})
    client.set_use_https(False)

    for feed in feeds:
        print('Start extracting `{}` feed ({}/{})'.format(feed, feeds.index(feed)+1, len(feeds)))
        #print('Start extracting `'+str(feed)+'` feed ('+str(feeds.index(feed)+1)+'/'+str(len(feeds))+')')
        poll_request = tm11.PollRequest(generate_message_id(),
                                        collection_name=feed,
                                        subscription_id=generate_message_id())
        poll_xml = poll_request.to_xml(pretty_print=True)
        http_resp = client.call_taxii_service2('hailataxii.com', '/taxii-data', VID_TAXII_XML_11, poll_xml)
        taxii_message = t.get_message_from_http_response(http_resp, poll_request.message_id)
```

I expected creation of an XML file in results directory because the code after **get_message_from_http_response()** function writes the response in an XML format. All feeds were extracted successfully except blutmagie_de_torExits, dataForLast_7daysOnly and phishtank_com.
Error in console is

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "hailataxii_feeds_saver.py", line 63, in <module> 
    feeds.feeds_arg, result_folder.result_folder_arg) 
 File "hailataxii_feeds_saver.py", line 31, in main 
    http_resp, poll_request.message_id) 
 File "/home/bscs8/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtaxii/ init .py", li ne 47, in get_message_from_http_response 
    return get_message_from_urllib_addinfourl(http_response, in_response_to) 
 File "/home/bscs8/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtaxii/ init .py", li ne 109, in get_message_from_urllib_addinfourl 
    return tmll.get_message_from_xml(response_message, encoding) 
 File "/home/bscs8/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libtaxii/messages_11.py", line 75, in get_message_from_xml 
    xml_string = xml_string.decode(encoding, 'replace') 
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode 
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) 
MemoryError
```

Comment: You tagged this with `python-3.x`, but your traceback makes it clear you're running Python 2.7. Which one did you intend to be using? You also seem to have left out what the memory usage was after six hours.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowRanger yes I mentioned python-3.x although I used Python 2.7, the feeds can be fetched by any version of Python greater than 2.
Moreover I was looking at memory usage. I started the feed at 8:00 PM and checked the system status at 11:00PM, the memory usage was 6.3GiB(40.5%) of 15.6GiB and network history showed 3.6GiB recieved.
I checked again at 1:00 AM, the memory usage was 8.5GiB(54.3%) of 15.6GiB and network history showed 6.0GiB recieved.
After this, I again checked the system status at 8:30 AM where I got to see the Memory Error.